# collective.localfunctions prevents plone from starting

Tags: python-2.7

Plone 4.3.3

I am trying to get some extra python modules available to my plone scripts. 'Net search led me to collective.localfunctions, which supposedly demonstrates how to lighten up restricted python. I installed per the instructions:

```
git clone https://github.com/collective/collective.localfunctions
easy_install collective.localfunctions
# not installed where plone can get to it, so...
copy from system python lib to the plone build-cache/eggs director
added collective.localfunctions to eggs = and zcml =
```

Running buildout and restarting results in a non-responsive site, nothing is listening on 8080. There is nothing useful in var/log, either.
So, bottom line question is, how do I enable python modules, specifically re and datetime?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to allow extra modules to be used in restricted python is outlined in the answer to this [Importing ping module in RestrictedPython script in Plone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576938/importing-ping-module-in-restrictedpython-script-in-plone)